# Wordpress Spotify playlist Embed, '&theme=white' gets encoded

Tags: wordpress, iframe, spotify, playlist, ampersand

I'm trying to get some spotify playlists on a blog with the white theme.
No idea why the ampersand of `'&theme=white'` gets encoded.
I have tried commenting the lines in formatting.php

```
//$curl = preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-zA-Z1-4]{1,8};)/', '&#038;$1', $curl);
```

and

```
//$url = str_replace( '&amp;', '&#038;', $url );
```

But it still gets encoded...
I'm using the Bridge Theme with WPBakery and Visual composer.
Are those guys messing with the encoding probably?

Here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/2hbw7tsQv6Ejqc8kBDoFIK&theme=white" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

& is only used between different query parameters

? is only used between the path and the query parameters

Since you only have one query parameter, just change & into a ?